# Importance of 6PM in the bank run scene from "It's a Wonderful Life"

Tags: plot-explanation, its-a-wonderful-life

At the end of the bank run scene from "It's a Wonderful Life", special significance is given to 6 PM.  That is, Potter warns George, "If you close your doors before 6 PM you will never reopen!"  Also, George et al at Building and Loan excitedly count down to 6 PM.

What is the reason for this?  When George initially arrives at the B&L, Uncle Billy had already locked the doors.  Other than not wanting to lose his customers' confidence, is there some particular necessity to be open until 6?

Comment: The S&L had to stay open for its posted hours of business to avoid the appearance they were insolvent and ducking their depositors.  Closing early would have given Potter all he needed to goose the panic and buy people's accounts for 50 cents on the dollar. Uncle Billy had panicked and closed the doors, which George realized was not the wisest course.

Comment: So, this wasn’t a legal requirement?

Comment: Not from some cursory reading.

Comment: Would you like to post that as the answer?